# Pi-hole vs dd-wrt script

Tags: networking, pi-hole

I own a TP Link 1043nd router with dd-wrt on it. I am able to block ads in my whole network using a firewall script. I am considering to build a pi-hole ad blocker. Is it a good idea to shift to pi hole from dd-wrt based ad blocking considering that my router have only 32 RAM.

Comment: i don't know what's in your script, but the advantages of pi-hole are that you get constant updates, high configurability in a ready to go package.  I've enjoyed it's ad-blocking.  You don't have to update your script, just click update in pi-hole to update the blocklists.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think the firewall script uses Thad manny re-souses, so the possible drawback (to slowdown your connection)  wond be that much of a deal as far is I can predict.

if i were you i'll use your pi for an other project.